# How to move a multi-module project from eclipse to IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, module

I want to move a multi-module project from eclipse to IDEA and that is not a maven project. What's the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Importing an Eclipse project to IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html#migratingEclipseProject).